# MachineLearning tflearn/tensorflow images to greyscale

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tflearn

I am currently trying to develop a CNN with tflearn, to detect Objects. My data comes from a pickle file, so I do not have any .png files or similar. My images are stored as numpy.array with the shape:

```
 (34799, 32, 32, 3)
```

34799 is the number of images, so basically the shape is 32,32,3.

my CNN is defined as the following:

```
    import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, fully_connected, flatten, dropout
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.metrics import Accuracy

# Building convolutional network
def neural_network(X, y, dropoutRate=0.8):
    network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3], name='input')

    network = conv_2d(network, nb_filter=6, filter_size=5, strides=1, activation='relu', padding="VALID")

    network = conv_2d(network, 6, 4, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)

    network = conv_2d(network, 16, 5, strides=1, activation="relu", padding="VALID")
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 2, padding="VALID")

    network = dropout(incoming=network, keep_prob=dropoutRate)
    network = fully_connected(network, 84, activation="relu")
    network = flatten(network)
    network = fully_connected(network, 43, activation='softmax')

    acc = Accuracy()
    network = regression(network, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.001,
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='target')
    # Training
    model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
    model.fit(X_test, y_test, n_epoch=7, batch_size=20, show_metric=True, snapshot_epoch=True, run_id="trafficSign", snapshot_step=500, validation_set=(X_valid, y_valid))
    return model
```

my problem is that, when I turn the images to gray with the built-in tensor flow function:

```
tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(X_train)
```

so that is the tensor coming from the function

```
<tf.Tensor 'rgb_to_grayscale_6:0' shape=(34799, 32, 32, 1) dtype=float64>
```

but when changing the first part of my CNN. The input_data() to the shape [32,32,1] I get an error that the shape is wrong and it can't fill the shape because it has the shape [32,32].

So my question is, is there an easy way to append the ,1 to my shape?

Thanks for all your help and please tell me if you need any more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st solution You can do the changes inside the netwrok

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3], name='input')
network = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(network)
network = conv_2d(network, nb_filter=6, filter_size=5, strides=1, activation='relu', padding="VALID")
...
```

2nd Solution
 : Apart from that you can reduce the extra complexity of converting the data every epochs

use PIL/opencv to convert your RGB images to gray

```
  now you have X_TRAIN = (34799, 32, 32)
  # conver the input into 4D
  X_TRAIN = np.expand_dims(X_TRAIN, 3)
```

use the minor modified version of the first code

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 1], name='input')
network = conv_2d(network, nb_filter=6, filter_size=5, strides=1, activation='relu', padding="VALID")
...
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and first got a dtype error. After casting the data back into float32. the following error occurred.
the file should not be larger than 2GB, which is impossible. The training set has 104 mb in size. I would upload a picture, but I don't know how

Comment: you mightn't be using the correct way to feed the data. look at `tflearn` docs http://tflearn.org/helpers/trainer/

Comment: I will try out your second approach once I am back from work. Thank you so much!